# Limitar um loop

Tags: php, html, css

Estou praticando recentemente o PHP e sei fazer um loop com o While, mas queria limitar esse loop para não quebrar uma coluna do site.

```
<?php

        include_once 'conexao.php';

        $sql = "select * from perfil";

        $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    ?>
                <article class="novos-titulos">
<h3><a href="perfil.php?idperfil=<?php echo $row["idperfil"];?>"><?php echo mb_strimwidth($row["titulo"], 0, 20, "..." ); ?></a></h3>

                    <a href="perfil.php?idperfil=<?php echo $row["idperfil"];?>"><img src="img/<?php echo $row["capa"]; ?>" alt=""></a>
                    <span>Total: <?php echo $row["episodios"]; ?></span>

                </article>
  <?php } mysqli_close($con);?>
            </div>
```

Comment: O que você deseja é colocar um ponto de parada no laço correto? Pode criar uma variável count para parar o loop ou usar um for (https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp)

Comment: if($count == 10)  break;

Comment: Então. Eu quero que ele pare de adicionar item a coluna. Limitar a 5 itens.

Comment: Como assim colunas? O código não gera vários <articles> um embaixo do outro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma solução, até eficiente, para limitar o número de iterações no loop é limitar o retorno da consulta SQL (isso evita o carregamento de dados que não serão utilizados):

```
select * from perfil limit 5;
```